# Blender results turning wild after switching to render mode

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shader-nodes, pbr

I am working on one of my blender files for two weeks now when two days ago all of a sudden the results in render mode were turning wild:

- One of the floors turned black when in render mode (it didnt the last 14 days) while the others (all textured the same through  PBR) still work fine. Here you can see the difference between Render mode and Viewport Shader:
  [image: Floor in render mode]
  [image: Floor in Viewport Shader]
- at least one of the glass cubes are rendered black while the others are rendered properly (altough they all share the same material)
  [image: Glass cubes in render mode]
  [image: Glass Nodes]
- the floor level of one of the corridors appears to have lowered when in render mode although all floors are built through modifiers (and in Viewport Shader one can see that it has still the same level as all the other rooms)
  [image: Corridor floor in render mode]
  [image: Corridor floor in Viewport Shader]

All these things appeared out of nowhere when adding new objects to the scene. And while one problem showed two days ago another just yet appeared. I am more than happy to share the file with anyone who wants to help.

Thanks already
Fabienne

Comment: and why didn't you share your blend file...?

Comment: Just to clarify, you mention _Render Mode_ and _Viewport Shader_ (I assume those are the top 2 images) - For your render engine, you have chosen Cycles (Which means Render Preview will be in Cycles), but Viewport Shading (Material Preview) uses EEVEE to render the scene (not the same as cycles) - what engine do you plan to use for the final render? (I assume Cycles). If that is the case, know there are large differences between Cycles and eevee regarding how _Transparency_ and _Displacement_ are handled - Transparent Materials in eevee need the Blend Mode changed or they will appear black.

Comment: Displacement (most likely through the shader) may be responsible for the floor height changing - Displacement does nothing to mesh vertex positions in EEVEE, but can change them easily in Cycles (depending on the midlevel).